# Chilli leaf curl downwards

Tags: diseases, chili, wilt

I have few chilli plants in a medium sized pot. Last few days I could notice some of the leaves are curling downwards and there is no color change. I am unable to find other issues in the plant. I could see few leaves in the plant is like that and rest of the plants seems to be all good in the same pot. Can you please make me understand as what is the problem with my plant. And the plant is just one month old and there are no flowers right now. [image][image]

Comment: Can you add a photograph please? Otherwise, are you saying the leaves are wilting, dangling downwards,or turning themselves upside down? And where are these plants, outdoors? In sun or not?

Comment: Added the photos. I have used garlic and neem pesticides to avoid any possible pest problems.

Comment: Yes the plants are placed outdoor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of different possibility's that would explain what you are seeing and have shown here in these pictures; including something as simple as the time of day.

Here are my top three guesses:

- Over watering: Drooping leaves, curling downward from the stem to the tip.

The solution here is obvious; decrease your watering scheduled and or give the plant more sunlight.

- Phosphorus Deficiency: Lower leaves look dark green or bluish and appear shiny. May have splotches that look brown or bronze. Affected leaves curl downward.

A possible solution is to add a bone meal based supplement: [LINK](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/uses-bonemeal-vegetable-gardens-77053.html)

- Nitrogen Deficiency: Lower leaves look yellow and become soft and curl inward. May then turn brown before falling off.

A possible solution is to add a nitrogen fertilizing compound: [LINK](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/garden-how-to/soil-fertilizers/nitrogen-plant-fertilizer.htm)

Currently I do not believe the plant is in any harm but with that being said I would suggest you slightly decrease the amount of water your chili plants are receiving (very slight) at first in order to eliminate it as the most likely culprit. Assuming of course that there are no bugs or other symptoms you haven't mentioned.

Comment: Hi Rob thanks for your reply I have placed the pot where the light comes to the full. Will check for few days and will post you. But today it is cloudy and I didn't see sun.

Comment: Hi Rob today I was able to see some tiny  brown spots in top of few leaves is that could be because of what you already told - phosphorus deficiency?  If so you have suggested to add a bone supplement can u add this for all the vegetables and flower plants that I have like tomatoes, egg plants, okra, beans?  And flowers like hibiscus and roses? Please let me know this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user23599 Yes you can that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks Rob do we have any measurements for this?

Comment: @user23599 They make this stuff specifically for gardening. So there will be directions on the bag for you to follow. If not, then come back and post another question.